# Boost libraries <limits> file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, boost

I am trying to use the Boost libraries within a simple Xcode (6.1.1) project.
I installed Boost using homebrew and I edited my project’s Header Search Paths adding:

```
/usr/local/include (non recursive)
```

When I use

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp>
```

I don’t have any immediate problem, but if I try to compile, I get the error: ‘limits’ file not found
This error is triggered by the command

```
#include <limits>
```

in the bessel.hpp header.
The path of the limits folder is:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/limits
```

but even if I modify the bessel.hpp header changing

```
#include <limits>
```

to

```
#include <boost/mpl/limits>
```

I still get ‘boost/mpl/limits’ file not found.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but even if I modify the bessel.hpp header changing `#include <limits>` to `#include <boost/mpl/limits>`

I don't even think it works with `#expect <spanish-inquisition.hh>`. You can't just change random headers. (Especially not when dropping the `.hpp` extension for no reason)

Anyways, `<limits>` is a standard library header (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits), so *don't change it*.

> As a general rule: ***don't change boost, standard library or whatever third-party library headers.***

If it isn't being found, you're either not using the correct compiler (C++, not C) or your installation is broken/misconfigured.

> **Hint**: Did you mean to *add* `/usr/local/include` to the include path instead of *replacing it*? Because standard library is usually somewhere under `/usr/include`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. As you may have surmised, I'm a newbie with C++. As it turns out I was in fact using the wrong compiler.